# Tensorflow Dimension size must be evenly divisible by N but is M for 'linear/linear_model/x/Reshape'

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, shapes, reshape

I've been trying to use tensorflow's `tf.estimator`, but I'm getting the following errors regarding the shape of input/output data.

> ValueError: Dimension size must be evenly divisible by 9 but is 12 for
>   'linear/linear_model/x/Reshape' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes:
>   [4,3], [2] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1]
>   = [?,9].

Here is the code:

```
data_size = 3
iterations = 10
learn_rate = 0.005
# generate test data
input = np.random.rand(data_size,3)
output = np.dot(input, [2, 3 ,7]) + 4
output = np.transpose([output])

feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x", shape=(data_size, 3))]
estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns)

input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({"x":input}, output, batch_size=4, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True)

estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=iterations)
```

input data shape is `shape=(3, 3)`:

```
[[ 0.06525168  0.3171153   0.61675511]
 [ 0.35166298  0.71816544  0.62770994]
 [ 0.77846666  0.20930611  0.1710842 ]]
```

output data shape is `shape=(3, 1)`

```
[[  9.399135  ]
 [ 11.25179188]
 [  7.38244104]]
```

I have sense it is related to `input` data, `output` data and `batch_size`, because when `input` data changed to 1 row it works. When `input` data rows count equal to `batch_size`(`data_size = 10` and `batch_size=10`) then it throws other error:

> ValueError: Shapes (1, 1) and (10, 1) are incompatible

Any help with the errors would be much appreciated.

Comment: I figured out solution, The issue was in input shape `(3,3)` but it should be `(3,)`, so I have made the change to `feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x", shape=(3,))]`, and it works perfectly.

Comment: I have run into the same problem, do you remember why you needed to change that? Thanks

Comment: @AdriánArroyoPerez You do not have to provide number of examples on your training set. For example:  `x.shape = 10, 5` then input shape will be `shape=(5,)` and so on. hope this help.