# Value Error problem for machine learning model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I got a ValueError when using TensorFlow to create a model. I have tried debugging and checked the shapes from my model. I don't understand how or what this error means but I've narrowed the problem down to the Conv2D layer as causing the error. I also tried changing hyperparamters (i.e., batch size, microbatches, etc.).

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

!pip install tensorflow-privacy
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow_privacy import *
import tensorflow_privacy

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models, losses
from tensorflow.keras import backend as bke
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l1, l2, l1_l2 #meaning of norm

from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

batch_size = 8
epochs = 4
microbatches = 8


inChannel = 1
kr = 0#1e-5
num_kernels=8
drop_perc=0.25
dim = 1

l2_norm_clip = 1.5
noise_multiplier = 1.3
 
learning_rate = 0.25
latent_dim = 0


def print_datashape():
  print('genotype data: ', genotype_data.shape)
  print('phenotype data: ', single_pheno.shape)


genotype_data = tf.random.uniform([4276, 28220],0,255,)
phenotype_data = tf.random.uniform([4276, 20],0,255,)

genotype_data = genotype_data.numpy()
phenotype_data = phenotype_data.numpy()

small_geno = genotype_data
single_pheno = phenotype_data[:, 1]

print_datashape()

df = small_geno
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
df = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(df)
scaled_pheno = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(single_pheno.reshape(-1,1)).reshape(-1)

feature_size= df.shape[1]
df = df.reshape(-1, feature_size, 1, 1)



print("df: ", df.shape)
print("scaled: ", scaled_pheno.shape)


# split train to train and valid
train_data,test_data,train_Y,test_Y = train_test_split(df, scaled_pheno, test_size=0.2, random_state=13)
train_X,valid_X,train_Y,valid_Y = train_test_split(train_data, train_Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=13)

def print_shapes():
  print('train_X: {}'.format(train_X.shape))
  print('train_Y: {}'.format(train_Y.shape))
  print('valid_X: {}'.format(valid_X.shape))
  print('valid_Y: {}'.format(valid_Y.shape))

input_shape= (feature_size, dim, inChannel)

predictor = tf.keras.Sequential()
predictor.add(layers.Conv2D(num_kernels, (5,1), padding='same', strides=(12, 1), activation='relu',input_shape= input_shape))
predictor.add(layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,1)))
predictor.add(layers.Dropout(drop_perc))
predictor.add(layers.Flatten())
predictor.add(layers.Dense(int(feature_size / 4), activation='relu'))
predictor.add(layers.Dropout(drop_perc))
predictor.add(layers.Dense(int(feature_size / 10), activation='relu'))
predictor.add(layers.Dropout(drop_perc))
predictor.add(layers.Dense(1))

optimizer = DPKerasAdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate, l2_norm_clip=l2_norm_clip, noise_multiplier=noise_multiplier, num_microbatches=microbatches)

# compile
predictor.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mse'])

#summary
predictor.summary()

print_shapes()

predictor.fit(train_X, train_Y,batch_size=batch_size,epochs=epochs,verbose=1, validation_data=(valid_X, valid_Y))
```

```
ValueError: Dimension size must be evenly divisible by 8 but is 1 for '{{node Reshape}} = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32](mean_squared_error/weighted_loss/value, Reshape/shape)' with input shapes: [], [2] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [8,?].
```

Comment: Try changing `num_kernels=8` to 1. Error is most likely directly due to input parameters, not data structure.

Comment: I get same error @Ghoti, after changing num_kernels=1

Comment: The `import`s look like you are using Python 2; is that correct?

Comment: Hey @tripleee i'm using python version 3.7.15

Comment: I did fix the error after changing my loss function. I set loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE). Afterwards my model wasn't performing well. I tried to add a kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L1(kr) to my Conv2D layer, with kr=1e-5. But I get another error: `ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 1 and 0
     From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for '{{node AddN}} = AddN[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT](mean_squared_error/weighted_loss/Mul, conv2d_2/kernel/Regularizer/mul)' with input shapes: [?], [].`

Comment: I've made a new post with the current issue/problem and with the updated code here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74423860/value-error-problem-from-kernel-regularizer)

Comment: Hi @x1Hawkx24, could you please refer to this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47661657/tensorflow-dimension-size-must-be-evenly-divisible-by-n-but-is-m-for-linear-lin) and let us know if it helps or not. Thank You.